# Как получить элементы из Shadow DOM (close)

Tags: javascript, node.js, html5, puppeteer

Есть тестовая страница

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru-RU">
<head xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Тестовая страница для парсинга Shadow DOM</title>

    <script>
        customElements.define("show-yatag", class extends HTMLElement {
          connectedCallback() {
            const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'closed'});
            shadow.innerHTML = "<p id='one'>Hello World!</p>";
          }
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Тестовая страница для парсинга Shadow DOM</h1>

    <show-yatag></show-yatag>
</body>
</html>
```

Формирует следующий код в devtools
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли забрать данные, те которые спрятаны в "show-yatag" используя NodeJS и puppeteer

Comment: ни как ! это не возможно скорее всего, элементы теневого DOM не видны из обычного DOM через querySelector

Comment: вы можете сами создавать собственный элемент в DOM но только один но и так же для каждого

Comment: Если сделаете, как `mode: 'open'`, то можете достать через `shadowRoot`.